# How to display the rows with the most number of occurrences in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with 6 columns:

```
   taken    person  quant   reading   personal  family
0   1       lake    rad      9.7      Anderson  Lake
1   1       lake    sal      0.21     Anderson  Lake
2   5       Lim     sal      0.08     Andy      Lim
3   2       Lim     rad      9.82     Andy      Lim
4   2       Lim     sal      0.13     Andy      Lim
5   3       dyer    rad      7.7      William   Dyer
```

Output i want:

```
   taken    person  quant   reading   personal  family
0   5       Lim     sal      0.08     Andy      Lim
1   2       Lim     rad      9.82     Andy      Lim
2   2       Lim     sal      0.13     Andy      Lim
```

Basically, i want to display all the rows in the df based on the most number of occurrences in the personal column. This is what i've tried but it doesn't work

```
test = df.personal.mode()
test1 = df.loc[df.personal == test]
display(test1)
```

Comment: you're halfway there, just need `test1 = df.loc[df.personal == test[0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `value_counts` and boolean indexing:

```
df[df['person'] == df['person'].value_counts().index[0] ]
```

Output:

```
   taken person quant  reading personal family
2      5    Lim   sal     0.08     Andy    Lim
3      2    Lim   rad     9.82     Andy    Lim
4      2    Lim   sal     0.13     Andy    Lim
```

Note that this only keep one `person` in the case there are several persons with same number of appearances. If you want to keep all of them, `mode` and `isin` is a better choice:

```
df[df['person'].isin(df['person'].mode())]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about that